# Что значит n - 1 в оценке алгоритма?

Tags: c, алгоритм

приложу скриншот
[image: часть из книги]

Я высшую математику не знаю. Пробовал читать математический анализ, но забросил. Сейчас опять есть интерес читать, но хочу на английском почитать, может там будет лучше объяснять. Самостоятельно сложно некоторые вещи понимать, жаль что в даже в книгах авторы подразумевают, что читатель сам поймет. Также посоветуйте книги, чтобы я мог самостоятельно по книгам понять. По видео на youtube по оценке алгоритма, я понял что n -  это бесконечно большое число, то есть линейный поиск до максимального числа. Но мне сложно понять что такое n - 1, я никак логически не могу понять какое объяснение вкладивается в эту запись. начиная с 5 строки, есть  E. Как я помню из математического анализа - из вводной части, это объясняется как сумма из n. это вроде что j принадлежит множеству n, которая n является линейной. из этой книги по алгоритму 2tj означает это смещение влево например на один. то есть в этой книге объяснялась двоичная арифметика. сдвиг числа влево на бит, что означает умножение на 2. то есть 2tj принадлежит множеству j. но в этом случае это означает простой сдвиг вниз по индексу. а 2(tj - 1) это тоже самое наверное что и n - 1, только для j. я думаю что не всё правильно понимаю, но можете пожалуйста объяснить это так, чтобы было понятно даже ничему не сведущему в математике.

Comment: n здесь это количество элементов в сортируемом массиве.

Comment: *объяснить это так, чтобы было понятно даже ничему не сведущему в математике* — вряд ли...

Comment: Оценка алгоритмов строится на математике, поэтому и подразумевается, что читающий её как минимум знает. При этом высшая математика, это не только математический анализ, это совокупность различных разделов и из каждой вам нужно знать хотя бы основные сведения. Нужно уметь оперировать буквами, в данном случае буква `n` ничем не отличается от букв a,b,c или более привычной нам x. К примеру, если кол-во элементов x=100, то логично что x-1=99. Просто нас обычно интересует большое число элементов, возьмите к примеру n = 1000000 если хотите.

Comment: Опять же, что такое сумма, знать высшую математику не обязательно, это просто способ записи через сигму (E): https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сумма_(математика) Ну могу еще этот сайт посоветовать почитать по математике: http://www.mathprofi.ru/matematika_dlya_chainikov.html Но советуют смотреть не только на мат. анализ.

Comment: В той же википедии можно найти этот алгоритм с тем же анализом.  Может будет понятней https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сортировка_вставками

Comment: @AlexKrass ну вот например n == 10. тогда n - 1 равно 9, но почему это равно 9, когда идет простое присваивание из массива по индексу. я вот как раз этого не пойму.

Comment: @switcher у вас в массиве 10 элементов, сколько раз произойдет присваивание элемента, если начальный индекс присваивания у нас на 1 больше (смотрим внимательно, что `j = 2`)?

Comment: @AlexKrass опа, спасибо. я даже и не подумал об этом. просто в программировании есть правило что весь отчет всегда начинается с нуля и поэтому не понимал что j = 2 это второе число, я думал что оно третье. блин. спасибо. как все понятно стало.

Comment: Не в программировании, а в конкретных языках. Здесь же даже не язык программирования, а псевдокод...

Comment: По большому счёту (n-1) **в оценке** ничем не отличается от n. Смотри про O-нотацию. https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%ABO%C2%BB_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%C2%ABo%C2%BB_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5

Comment: @AlexKrass, вы не правы насчёт выбранных букв. Как латинские, так и греческие буквы используются не рандомно, а в зависимости от контекста, часто подразумевая некие стандарты **на практике**. Так, n — number, поэтому a, b или c только внесёт путаницу.

Comment: @0andriy, речь об умении оперировать в выражениях различными переменными. Говоря, что я не прав, вы подразумеваете сейчас, что если вдруг в выражении я заменю n на другую букву, то что-то вдруг изменится? Что само по себе неверно и Кормен дальше по книге вывалит на вас весь спектр букв, который только понадобится (n,i,j,n,m,k,q, r...). И с этим придется разбираться. А по поводу контекста, в книгах это пишут отдельно, если хотят выделить и осознанный выбор никто не отменял. А вообще пустой спор из ничего, моя мысль о другом.